# Sort files by name length in finder?

Tags: finder, file, sort

I want to be able to find all mp3 files with exactly 4 letters so i can highlight them and open them up in ITunes. How do I do this?

I recently copied mp3s from my iPod to my mac. These files are all labelled with 4 random letters (eg. WRXL) and only reveal the name of the artist and song once opened in iTunes. When I highlighted all the files and double clicked and most of them opened up iTunes and became properly labelled, however i am left with about 2000 songs with the weird labels. These files are scattered through different albums and artists, so i need to find a way to group them all together so i can open them at the same time.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can make it from **Terminal.app**. Open Terminal, navigate to the folder where Your music is (here's example for iTunes library):

```
cd ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Music/
```

Then run this command:

```
find . -name "[[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]].mp3" -exec open {} \;"
```

This will find all 4 letters mp3 files, for example `XXXX.mp3` and open them in default app.

---

<sup>Pattern in the `find` command could be shortened, but I can't find it right now.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use the Recently Added smartlist & sort by date added.

You can't search by '4 random characters'.